# Can one say the b'rocho of borai meorai hoeash on stars

Tags: halacha, havdalah, astronomy

On motsai shabbos we make *havdala* and also make a *b'rocho borai morai hoeish* on what is called today the havdala. If one does not have one and no means of making a 'light' can one make the b'rocho on the stars? This question has to do with psochim 2a where is it discussed if the light of stars is called 'ohr'.

Comment: questions on present daf yomi

Comment: Stars were created before shabbas,fire was created motzei shabbas

Comment: @sam The yaavets in mor ukztsia 296 gives that reason for not saying it amongst others. But almost everyone else like the tur says you can. All my posts today on psochim are taken from the new mesivta gemoro.

Comment: I thought we need a torch and a fire lit after Shabbos. Though for Motzai Yom Kippour the question stands.

Comment: @Danny Schoemann No even on yom kippur you can light the 'torch' then. It must only not have been lit on shabbos. The real answer is it depends if stars are made of fire.

Comment: @annex, that's realy "last choice" בדיעד as stated in the Kitzur Shulchan Oruch 133:28

Comment: @DannySchoemann Shabbat can use a day old flame like Yom Kippur; it just doesn't need it.

Answer (score 5):

[Rokeach at the end of 356 - in this linked edition it is on page 242 line 5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21522&st=&pgnum=271&hilite=) says that if one is travelling he can stretch out his hands to the light of the stars and say Borai Meorai Haeish. He does not say anything regarding Shem U'Malchus.

However the [Raviya Brachos](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37766&st=&pgnum=83&hilite=) clearly says he should say it with Shem U'Malchus.

> ואם  היה בדרך פושט ידיו לאור הכוכבים שהם של אש ואומר בא״י אמ״ה  בורא
>   מאורי האש

Comment: Is there any indication if we paskin this way?